# trouble with jquery/instagram plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://github.com/potomak/jquery-instagram

For the life of me I can't seem to get this plugin by potomak working (per the instructions). Simply nothing is showing up. I have tried a dozen times.

Using the code off the actual coders site works fine, but its a bit different from the manual. Any ideas whats going on?

This works:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var clientId = 'xxxx';

  $(".instagram.tag").instagram({
    hash: 'motohouston',
    image_size: 'low_resolution',
    show: 80,
    clientId: clientId
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Looks like there is a conflict with another script somewhere. Works fine on a simple independent page.